# Compiling tinyB bluetooth library

Tags: bluetooth, compiling

I am trying to compile TinyB library from Intel. I found this script:
https://gist.github.com/StevenRudenko/b6c032c3c1fdfb5c641ff95883e6cd02

```
https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb

https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/12/19/tutorial-ble-pairing-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-hexiwear/


# Update BlueZ
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git build-essential autoconf cmake libtool libglib2.0 libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev
wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.39.tar.xz
tar xvf bluez-5.39.tar.xz 
cd bluez-5.39/

aclocal 
autoheader 
automake --force-missing --add-missing 
autoconf
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd

./configure --prefix=/usr \
            --mandir=/usr/share/man \
            --sysconfdir=/etc \
            --localstatedir=/var \
            --enable-experimental \
            --enable-maintainer-mode

make
sudo make install
sudo cp attrib/gatttool /usr/local/bin
sudo sed -i '/^ExecStart.*bluetoothd\s*$/ s/$/ --experimental/' /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
sudo ln -s /lib/firmware /etc/firmware
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo apt-mark hold bluez



sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
  ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental  
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

bluetoothctl
  power on
  agent on
  scan on
  scan off
  info 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  pair 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  devices
  list-attributes 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  read
  atribute-info
  select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_32_40_08_00_12/service002e/char002f
  write 0x3 0x4 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40
  disconnect 00:32:40:08:00:12
  quit

sudo apt-get install cmake build-essentials check-install libglib2.0-dev doxygen

git clone https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb.git

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILDJAVA=ON ..
make
sudo checkinstall install
// to remove dpkg -r build

java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/RXTXcomm.jar -jar your.jar
```

but this is a bit irrelevant. Could you help me fix this?

Firstly:

This script wants to compile bluez-5.39 with the -enable-experimental flag. Is it really necessary now? Can I just download the newest release of the library? If not, then when compiling BlueZ, there are many warnings that complete the compilation with the -Werror flag. Also, there is a problem with the “SIOCGSTAMP” function and I don’t know which function should I use here: “SIOCGSTAMP_NEW” or “SIOCGSTAMP_OLD”?

Second: `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth` does not work, due `Unit file /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service is masked.` Should I unmasked it?

Third: what exactly does this command do:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
  ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental
```

and why I need it?

I did not go further through the script, because the third part seems meaningless to me. Why duplicate ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental at the beginning of the file? I hope for your help.

Maybe some repository already has a compiled tinyB library that will work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it.
I was used SIOCGSTAMP_OLD, ignore weird edition: "

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
  ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental
```

", (that was enought):

```
sudo sed -i '/^ExecStart.*bluetoothd\s*$/ s/$/ --experimental/' /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
```

ignore part: "

```
bluetoothctl
  power on
  agent on
  scan on
  scan off
  info 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  pair 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  devices
  list-attributes 00:34:40:0A:00:4E
  read
  atribute-info
  select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_32_40_08_00_12/service002e/char002f
  write 0x3 0x4 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40
  disconnect 00:32:40:08:00:12
  quit
```

"
and compile like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILDJAVA=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
make install
```

https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/issues/27

TinyB works for me now, both c++ and Java version.
Good luck.